# I can't find a way to compile python on windows with mingw

Tags: c, python-3.x, windows, mingw

I recently installed MinGW on my windows machine. I am writing this on my linux computer and I currently am trying to compile python 3.7.0. I already had git so I ran `./configure` and it said I needed `pthreads`. I don't think I should use `autoconf`. What should I do? Is there a version FOR MinGW? (not using `mingw-w64` btw)

Comment: Sounds like you need the pthreads library.  Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: @jwdonahue Yes. didn't work. I tried multipule ones and found no luck doing it.

Comment: @lolz152: You can try the version for msys2.